# iOS 6+ native Facebook login

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I would like to implement the iOS native Facebook login (w/ a fallback to the fast-app switch & web login).

According to Facebook's documentation ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#iosintegration ), here's the way to do it (1st step) :

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                               allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                              /* handle success + failure in block */
                          }];
```

But this code does not show the native login dialog and opens the Facebook app even if I have a Facebook account setup in my iPhone.

Comment: try using accounts framework for users credentials.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but this solution doesn't have any fallback in case the user has not setup a Facebook account in his iPhone.